# How to check for null in Linq query

Tags: c#, linq

This linq:

```
list.AddRange(from modelState in context.ModelState.Values 
              from error in modelState.Errors 
              select error.Exception.ToString());
```

works if there is an `error.Exception`. However, if `error.Exception` is `null`, it throws a null ref error. How do I modify this to check for null?

Comment: When you got nulls what do you want to do with it? Filter it out? Or just have `null` items instead?

Comment: Just filter out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `Where` clause:

```
from modelState in context.ModelState.Values 
from error in modelState.Errors 
where error.Exception != null
select error.Exception.ToString()
```

And maybe you will find using `SelectMany` a bit more readable:

```
from m in context.ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors)
where m.Exception != null
select m.Exception.ToString()
```

In case you want `null` items where `error.Exception` is null then use the `?.` operator:

```
context.ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors.Select(e => e.Exception?.ToString())
```